# Nest all un-nested XML elements into a new element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an XML file that needs some corrections in its structure. Because of the size of said document this has to be done automatically.
The basic structure is the following:

```
<body>
    <div author='author1'>
        <lb n='1'/>Text1
        <lb n='2'/>Text2
    </div>
    <lb n='3'/>Text3
    <lb n='4'/>Text4
    <div author='author1'>
        <lb n='5'/>Text5
    </div>
    <add>xyz</add>
    <lb n='6'/>Text6
    <lb n='7'/>Text7
    <lb n='8'/>Text8
</body>
```

What I want to do is to put everything that isn't already in `div` tags into `div` tags and mark it with the attribute `@author='author2'`. The text and structure of the moved chunks should stay as it is, just nested into a `div`. The order has to be conserved as well.
The resulting XML should look something like this:

```
<body>
    <div author='author1'>
        <lb n='1'/>Text1
        <lb n='2'/>Text2
    </div>
    <div author='author2'>
        <lb n='3'/>Text3
        <lb n='4'/>Text4
    </div>
    <div author='author1'>
        <lb n='5'/>Text5
    </div>
    <div author='author2'>
        <add>xyz</add>
        <lb n='6'/>Text6
        <lb n='7'/>Text7
        <lb n='8'/>Text8
    </div>
</body>
```

My current XSLT (which I wrote before noticing that the XML has more elements than just `lb`) does put `lb` in the correct `div`, but it moves everything to the bottom and deletes the text.
The XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="body">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::lb)]"/>
            <div>
                <xsl:attribute name="resp">author2</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="lb"/>
            </div>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And it returns this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body><div author="author1">
        <lb n="1"/>Text1
        <lb n="2"/>Text2
    </div><div author="author1">
        <lb n="5"/>Text5
    </div><add>xyz</add><div resp="author2"><lb n="3"/><lb n="4"/><lb n="6"/><lb n="7"/><lb n="8"/></div></body>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to using `group-adjacent`, you could use `group-starting-with` on the `xsl:for-each-group`

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="div">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
        <xsl:if test="current-group()[2]">
          <div resp="author2">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[position() gt 1]"/>
          </div>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This one works great, thank you! It even permits having further nodes nested in the Text.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping in XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="self::lb or self::add">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <div author='author2'>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </div>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates  select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

See transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2CW

Comment: I think your approach is fine but your suggestion ignores text nodes, you need `<xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="self::lb or self::add or self::text()[normalize-space()]">` instead of `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="self::lb or self::add">`, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2CW/1, otherwise contents like `Text3` gets lost.